# Delete an item with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to delete an item after the user clicks on the Delete button. Through the handleDelete function, I am passing an id (idBooks) via axios when the user clicks a book. How do I withdraw it from the click?

Below you will find the React code and then the backend side code in node js.

Frontend

```
(class extends React.Component {


handleDelete = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { book } = this.props;
    axios.delete("http://localhost:8081/delete", book.idBooks )
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.warn(err.warn);
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { book, classes } = this.props;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    return(
      <Paper className= { classes.marginTopBottom }>
       <h2 className={ classes.title }>
       { book.title }
       </h2><hr />
       <div className= { classes.scrollingDiv }>
       <p>
       { book.plot }
       </p>
       </div>
       <hr/>
       <div className={ classes.pStyle }>
       <p>Publish date:<br /> { new Date(book.publish_date).toLocaleDateString() }</p>
       <p>Author:<br /> { book.author }
       </p>
       <p>Genre:<br /> { book.genre }</p>
       </div>
       <div>
       { token && (
       <Button  className={ classes.delete } size="small" onClick={this.handleDelete} type="button" variant="contained" color="primary" 
        component= {Link} to="delete">
       Delete
       <DeleteIcon className={ classes.rightIcon } />
       </Button>
      )}
       </div>
       </Paper>
    )
  }
});
```

Backend

```
const deleteBook = (req, res) => {
const connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionProperties);
connection.connect();
const query = `DELETE FROM Books WHERE idBooks = ${ req.body.idBooks }`;
connection.query(query, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send('Book deleted correctly.');
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Do you have the `idBooks` anywhere in  your props?

Comment: first of all function must return something and you can do `if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }` and then `return res.status(200).send('book deleted correctly.')` without `else`

Comment: and can you show whole router code? are you using `delete` http method?

Answer (score 0):

I guess passing the parameter might help you fix this issue.

1. On the `delete` Button add a parameter to the `onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(e,book.idBooks)}`
2. Change the `handleDelete` function a bit as below

```
handleDelete = (e,idBooks) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.delete("http://localhost:8081/delete", idBooks )
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.warn(err.warn);
    });
  };
```

Comment: If you directly invoke the `handleDelete` in `onClick` handler as you have shown, it will be invoked at the render time. So should provide it as a function as below.
`onClick={() => this.handleDelete(e,book.idBooks)}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a prop `onDeleteCallback`, and on successful delete call that function with deleted book id. In parent component (with all the books are listed) update the state with filtered out books.